# How to hide an element from screen reader/voiceover

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have added the following html

```
<a href="url" aria-hidden="true">Read more</a>
```

to hide this element from screen reader but the screen reader still the `Read more`

I have also tried with `tabindex=-1` to this anchor tag and to its outer div but still the screen reader read the `Read more` text.

Is there any way to hide it from the screen reader?

Comment: have a look at this link http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/hidden2013.html

Comment: it says that `aria-hidden` is supported by chrome on mac. but is not working with me on chrome.

Comment: If you are using VoiceOver, then use Safari, not Chrome. VoiceOver users typically do not use Chrome (I have not encountered one in the real world) as VO is optimized for Safari.

Comment: I am using the `screen reader` extension for chrome.

Comment: You may want to look at [Screen Reader / Browser Combinations](http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey6/#browsercombos) and [Screen Readers Commonly Used](http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey6/#used). I wouldn't recommend using Chromevox with Chrome as your main tool for testing your pages.

Answer (score 1):

may be helpful:

[Notes on using ARIA in HTML](https://w3c.github.io/using-aria/#4thrule)

> Fourth rule of ARIA use
>
> Do not use role="presentation" or aria-hidden="true" on a visible
>   focusable element .

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried using role="presentation" ? It also work for chrome.

Regards,
sachin